# MySQL - Recursive Reorder Algorithm / UPDATE with Variable Incrementation

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

Sorry for the kind of meaningless title, but I couldn't come up with a more fitting one.

---

I have a **MySQL table**, which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`

+----+-----------+----------+-------+
| id | dimension | order_by | value |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+
|  1 |     1     |     1    |  1st  |
|  2 |     1     |    100   |  3rd  |
|  3 |     2     |    300   |  5th  |
|  4 |     3     |    999   |  6th  |
|  5 |     1     |     2    |  2nd  |
|  6 |     2     |     1    |  4th  |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+
```

I am listing all entries ordered by `dimension` (first) and `order_by` (second), which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `dimension`, `order_by`

+----+-----------+----------+-------+
| id | dimension | order_by | value |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+
|  1 |     1     |     1    |  1st  |
|  5 |     1     |     2    |  2nd  |
|  2 |     1     |    100   |  3rd  |
|  6 |     2     |     1    |  4th  |
|  3 |     2     |    300   |  5th  |
|  4 |     3     |    999   |  6th  |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+
```

Now I'd like to write a function, that rearranges the `order_by`, if possible with just one `update` query, to make it look that way:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `dimension`, `order_by`

+----+-----------+----------+-------+
| id | dimension | order_by | value |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+
|  1 |     1     |     1    |  1st  |
|  5 |     1     |     2    |  2nd  |
|  2 |     1     |     3    |  3rd  |
|  6 |     2     |     1    |  4th  |
|  3 |     2     |     2    |  5th  |
|  4 |     3     |     1    |  6th  |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+
```

What I got so far (which, unfortunately, doesn't start recounting for each dimension):

```
UPDATE `table` AS `l`
JOIN (SELECT @i=1 FROM `table`) AS `i`
SET `order_by` = @i:=i
```

Now, my question would be: Is it possible to do it with just one `UPDATE` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to introduce another variable holding the value of the previous row.

```
UPDATE Table1 t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
  id, /*your primary key I assume*/
  @new_ob:=if(@prev != dimension, 1, @new_ob + 1) as new_ob,
  @prev := dimension /*In this line, the value of the current row is assigned. In the previous line, the variable still holds the value of the previous row*/
  FROM
  Table1
  , (SELECT @prev := null, @new_ob := 0) var_init_subquery
  ORDER BY dimension, order_by
) st ON t.id = st.id
SET t.order_by = st.new_ob;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51822/1/0)